# Write scala filter on data frame, a column should have more than two words

Tags: scala, apache-spark

val tempDf = Df.filter(Df("column_1")==="200")

now wanted to filter tempDf on basis of one column (column_2) which should have more than 2 words.

val extractedDf = tempDf.filter(*)

How we can write the filter in scala at *.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `size` and `split` function.

```
val extractedDf = tempDf.filter(size(split($"column_2"," ")) > 2)
```